# Is it possible to create a Dev Org from Full sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, sandbox-clone

I would like to create a Developer Edition Org from Full.

I haven't been able to find anything online for this, maybe I'm just bad at searching.

Is it possible? Is a specific license needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely not possible to create a Developer Edition Org from any Sandbox. Developer Edition Orgs are standalone instances not related to or based upon anything except the Salesforce-managed org template.

If you're talking about sandbox cloning, and want to create a new Developer or Developer Pro Sandbox, you can't do that from a Full Sandbox. Per the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_sandbox_clone.htm&type=5), you can only clone a Sandbox to the same sandbox license type:

> A cloned sandbox uses the same license type as its source org. For
>   example, to clone a Full sandbox you must have a Full sandbox license
>   available.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly tried doing so. UAT is our full copy sandbox

When I try to use sandbox clone functionality, it gives me Not enough license warning.

So to answer as of now, no you can't do that.

[image: Sandbox]

Answer (score -2):

The Sandbox option itself will not be available on the Setup of a Full Sandbox. Only if the Sandbox option is available on the Setup, you can create a Developer Sandbox.
[image: Sandbox option unavailable on a Full Sandbox]

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question, which appears to be about cloning sandboxes and/or sandbox templates.